# .NET DDD Domain Pattern with Grandchildren

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, domain-driven-design, domain-model

I would like to implement DDD Pattern in my .NET Core Domain Model.
Here is an example of the Aggregate Root with Aggregate Child Entity as well as Aggregate Grandchild Entity:

```
public class Supplier
    : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    private string _name;

    private readonly List<Catalog> _catalogs;
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Catalog> Catalogs => _catalogs;

    protected Supplier() { _catalogs = new List<Catalog>(); }

    public Supplier(string name)
    {
        _catalogs = new List<Catalog>();
        _name = name;
    }

    public void AddCatalog(string name)
    {
        var catalog = new Catalog(name);
        _catalogs.Add(catalog);
    }

    public void AddCatalogItem(int catalogId, string name)
    {
        var catalogItem = new CatalogItem(name);
        _catalogs.Single(c => c.Id == catalogId).AddCatalogItem(catalogItem);
    }
}
```

And here the code for the Aggregate Child:

```
public class Catalog
    : Entity
{
    private string _name;

    private readonly List<CatalogItem> _catalogItems;
    public IReadOnlyCollection<CatalogItem> CatalogItems => _catalogItems;

    protected Catalog() { _catalogItems = new List<CatalogItem>(); }

    public Catalog(string name)
    {
        _catalogItems = new List<CatalogItem>();
        _name = name;
    }

    public void AddCatalogItem(CatalogItem catalogItem)
    {
        _catalogItems.Add(catalogItem);
    }
}
```

And the Aggregate Grandchild:

```
public class CatalogItem
    : Entity
{
    private string _name;

    protected CatalogItem() { }

    public CatalogItem(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to accomplish DDD Pattern?
Or does this break DDD rules that I am not aware of?

Comment: There is no "DDD pattern" per se. DDD has a series of patterns that you can choose to use. As it is, your code fails to meet the bread and butter of DDD: a rich domain model - your entities don't have behavior or domain logic and don't enforce invariants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't break any DDD *rules* per se - but it is an approach that is often discouraged, for a few reasons:

- DDD encourages you to model the domain based on the operations, processes & rules that your system needs to support while managing *changes* to state.

  - The relationships you have modelled may exist in the real world - and they may help for visualising the data - but are they really necessary for your model?
- Good practice in DDD is to design *small* aggregates.  An aggregate is truly a 'consistency' boundary - the larger you make your consistency boundary you have a few consequences:

  - Most operations don't relate to all the data - but all the data must be transactionally locked during each operation
  - In collaborative multi-user domains this can lead to concurrency issues where either users are blocked due to the data they want to manipulate being locked unnecessarily
- Why *might* such relationships be useful to model?

  - If you had a rule (invariant) that MUST have transactionally consistent data across all the child aggregates, e.g.:

    - Must be at MOST 4 catalogs per supplier - to enforce this rule, you must have transactionally consistent list of catalogs in the supplier
    - The sum of the price  of catalogue items in a catalogue must not exceed $X - again, you need all the items in a transactionally consistent way

#### Alternatives

So - if you don't have any such rules, and you've been convinced to create 'small' aggregates, what can you do?

- Each entity becomes it's own aggregate
- Link entities by *reference*.  In this case:

  - Supplier would *not* have a list of catalogues
  - Catalog would have a 'SupplierId' to link the catalogue to the supplier, and facilitate obtaining the list of catalogues by supplier
  - Catalog would *not* have a list of CatalogItem
  - CatalogItem would have a 'CatalogId' to link to the catalog - again, facilitating obtaining the list of items by catalog

The implication of this approach is that you will *not* have transactional consistency across the aggregates - but unless your rules demand it, you don't need it, so why enforce it?

#### Do you really need transactional consistency?

Another piece of advice that DDD encourages is to challenge demands for transactional consistency - is it really really necessary?

Using the trivial example above - what would happen if a supplier ended up with 5 catalogs? would the world break? Even if you did need that that rule, does it need to be transactionally consistent?  With smaller aggregates, you could:

- Include client-side validation to prevent the operation if the supplier already had 4 catalogs
- Publish an event when a catalog is created, which triggers a check and compensating action - if the handler determines that the supplier now has 5 catalogs, raise an alert, or update the supplier state until the user removes a catalog, or automatically expire the oldest catalog - whatever makes the most sense in your domain

#### Summary

The recommendations are:

- Design small aggregates
- Embrace eventual consistency